# How to find out what information is used to generate hardware code

Tags: system-information

I have a commercial software product (Siemens WinCC), which generates a hardware code on the machine where it is running. I can use this code to request a license for my software installation.

The hardware code is generated by a small executable which does not more than just printing three lines to the console.

When I updated from openSuse 13.1 to 13.2, I got a problem:

The hardware code now depends on the network where I'm logged in. At my institute, there's a large wireless network with the same SSID, but being connected to different access points results in different codes. Being connected via ethernet cable, I do not get any code. Also, at home, I do not get any code.

As my problem appeared when switching from 13.1 to 13.2 and is related to the network, the problem must be located somewhere in the network management of openSuse.

So, my question is: I have a piece of software collecting various information from the PC. Is it somehow possible to find out what information is requested - or what information is given back by the system?

Comment: Have you used `strace` on the software?